# Average Time on SQL

Tags: sql, time, powerbi, average, reporting

I am working on a report where I need to find the average amount of time between two timestamps.

To find the time between the time stamps I used:

```
CAST(( Time2 - Time1 ) as time(0)) AS 'Time Between Stage1 and Stage2'
```

Now that I have that column, I am trying to get the Average Time Spent Between Stage1 and Stage2. I'm looking for the output to be in the **hh:mm:ss** format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Format(AVERAGE(CAST(( Time2 - Time1 ) as time(0)), "HH:MM: SS"))
```

Comment: I am getting the following Error: 
Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
The AVG function requires 1 argument(s).

Comment: That statement has a bracket mismatch, remove a bracket after CAST

Comment: Changed the answer.

Comment: Format(AVG(CAST((Time2-Time1) as time(0))), 'HH:MM:SS')
Error:
Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
Operand data type time is invalid for avg operator.

Answer (score 0):

declare @t1 datetime, @t2 datetime

```
set @t1 = '14:15:54'
set @t2 = '15:12:33'

select @t1,@t2

select cast(dateadd(ms, AVG(datediff( ms, @t1 ,@t2 )), '00:00:00') as time)
```

First, find the difference using DateDiff in the format of the lowest grain.
Then, find the average
Convert the Average back to date using the DateAdd (you will get errors if you try to use a cast or convert)
Finally, Cast back to a time

replace the variables with your attributes